# Error import SimpleCV in localhost

Tags: python, simplecv

This has bothered me all day and I haven't found solution online

import SimpleCV is working when I run script.py by itself,

The problem is when I'm trying to call the script.py from a form in localhost (apache)

I get import:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV 
  args = ('Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV',) 
  message = 'Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV'
```

I did a print sys.path and run the script myself and found both SimpleCV and OpenCV are listed, however when it's called via web form, both are missing.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have OpenCV installed?

Run:

```
ipython
> import cv2
> print cv2.__version__
```

Please report version back here.